# Is it possible to use DataBinding to evaluate Controls on .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm not sure if I am asking this question correctly.  I know that I can accomplish what I need in code behind, but I'm wondering if this is possible.  I want to hide a control  if there is a value in another control.  I know I can use databinder.eval in a repeater, but can I use it just for a normal asp control on the page?
In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConditionalText" Text="Show if other value is empty" Visible ='<%# testValue.Text != "" ? false : true %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="testValue"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried just the way I have it above, and `<%# testValue.` exposed available properties of "testValue" TextBox so I thought it might work.  It didn't throw any errors but it did not show/hide the textbox.  I'm just wondering if this is possible and what I would have to do to accomplish this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work, but since you are using a databinding expression outside a GridView, Repeater etc. you have to call it manually.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //rest of the code
    }

    //call databind manually
    DataBind();
}
```

PS better to use `IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `= ""`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConditionalText" Text="Show if other value is empty" 
  Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue.Text) ? false : true %>'></asp:TextBox>
```